# sources of glassfish-embedded-all-3.1.2.2.jar

Tags: java, glassfish, eclipselink

I'd like to get the sources of 
*glassfish-embedded-all-3.1.2.2.jar*.

But
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/main/extras/glassfish-embedded-all/3.1.2.2/glassfish-embedded-all-3.1.2.2-sources.jar
does only contain the pom.xml and the MANIFEST.MF, not any java source code.

I'm mainly interested in the part
*org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa* *(Bundle-Version: 2.3.4.v20160520-8886999)*
which should be available per Eclipse Public License.

But if I search for org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl on grepcode, a lot of versions from *1.0.1* to *2.6.1-RC1* are available, but between *2.1.1* and *2.4.2* is a big gap.
My first guess was that maybe there hasn't been a change from *2.1.1* to *2.3.4*, so this could be "my" version, but this version contains only javadoc at line 488 where "my" stacktrace (on the PROD server) raises an exception.
So this can not be the correct version, so:

> Where can I find the correct and (almost) complete sources of
>   glassfish-embedded-all-3.1.2.2.jar ?

Comment: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/persistence/eclipselink/2.3.4-M6/

Comment: thank you DN1. that's what I search for.

Comment: You should post this information as an answer so the question can be marked as solved :)